# What is returned by Storage.get in AWS Amplify when the file doesn't exist?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm trying to use AWS Ampify and can't find a good reference. [A guide](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/storage_guide), I can find, but not a reference. If I make a call to Storage.get, such as the code snippet below, and test.txt doesn't exist, what is returned?

```
Storage.get('test.txt')
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I'm finding that it returns a URL that results in a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Amplify 0.4.7, the intended behaviour is to [return a URL that results in a 404](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/1135).

If you want to avoid the 404, you can check for the presence of the file using Storage.list(). Or you can attempt to pre-load the URL with some exception handling, before actually use it.

This seems like sub-optimal behaviour to me, especially with a framework like angular, so I've submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/1145).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find out if the object exists in the bucket before creating a new one and this is how I did it, hope it helps.

```js
//make a get request of the object you want calling it by it's name
await Storage.get("key")
      .then((response) => { //The response is a url to the s3 object
        fetch(response).then((result) => { //fetch the URL
           if(result.status === 200) { //if the file exists
              console.log("file exists in the bucket");
           } else { //if the status is 403 or others, the s3 object doesn't exist
              console.log("file doesnt exist")
           }
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

**NOTE:**

My S3 Bucket permission is public read access. If you have differnt bucket permissions then this solution might not work for you.